# fixing the position of image

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am following the link to create a header and a footer and to place an image in between header and footer based on size of the image.

```
link is http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/yndsW/
```

But the problem is the image in between header and footer is scrolling vertically. 
    how can i avoid it and fix it to centre?

Comment: why not try to make height:100%; on img?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my another approach. Instead of using **img** tag I have decided to use background image and let css to handle centering. Javascript is only needed to dynamically change image.

We still need javascript to fix our page height. I have mailed you working project.

**HTML :**

```
<div data-role="page" id="Windage">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>


    <div data-role="content">

    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide">NEXT</a>
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}

.ui-content {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;  
    background-position: center center;
}
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#Windage', function(){       
    $('[data-role="content"]').height(getRealContentHeight());
    $('.ui-content').css('background-image','url(Image/timer.png)');    
});

function getRealContentHeight() {
    var header = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='header']:visible");
    var footer = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']:visible");
    var content = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
    var viewport_height = $(window).height();

    var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();
    if((content.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight()) <= viewport_height) {
        content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
    } 
    return content_height;
}
```

Also I made a slight change to your main project class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 360000); 
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-role="content" align="center">
  <div class="ui-center-image">
    <img src="http://www.wholelifepetsblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/cute-puppy.jpg"  height="100%" width="auto"/> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check the above code. I am not sure this is what your expectation ( of just center alignment of the image )

Oh Ok, This is browser compatible issue I guess. I have checked it chrome and I dint get any scroll but after that I have checked it in firefox now I can able to see your issue.

Comment: i have tried the above solution also. but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: I am trying it on emulator

Answer (score 0):

use css code a bit

`img
{
margin:  auto 0;
}`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yndsW/11/)

if you want the full screen for the image then

[try next](http://jsfiddle.net/yndsW/13/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use an old trick, add "`<center>`" to your code

> `<center>
>
>   <img src="http://www.wholelifepetsblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/cute-puppy.jpg" height="100%" width="auto"/>
>
>   </center>`

you should make sure that the width of the container is 100% ;)